# Windows Server 2008 DNS Transfer fail

Tags: windows

I have a serious problem. I want make child domains, my ISP was the master DNS server, but its changed and now he is the Slave, I'm the master, he must transfer my zone datas. When i want to setup the zone transfer on the zone named `creativevision.hu` I got an error to my ISP DNS server like `The server with this IP address is not authoritative for the required zone`. Plus when he want to download my zone datas he get an error:

```
Apr 25 20:49:04 core named[20917]: transfer of 'creativevision.hu/IN' 
from 78.131.7.21#53: failed while receiving responses: REFUSED
Apr 25 20:49:04 core named[20917]: transfer of 'creativevision.hu/IN' 
from 78.131.7.21#53: end of transfer
```

I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP will need to add the IP address of your DNS Server (78.137.7.21) as a trusted DNS server that it will accept transfers from.  Most ISPs will probably not do that.  My recommendation would be to change to a hosted DNS provider that will allow you to be master and they'll serve as slave.

I don't know offhand of one that will do this but I would check out www.ultradns.com or dns.com first and see if they have a solution.